# SQLAlchemy in Python query filtering through the wrong model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working with a small team on a school project, we are developing a Resume editing web application using flask in python. We finished the basic skeleton of the pages set up and now I am trying to figure out how I can save HTML to the SQLAlchemy database. Here is what I have:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column("email", db.String(100))
    username = db.Column("username", db.String(100))
    fname = db.Column("fname", db.String(20))
    lname = db.Column("lname", db.String(20))
    password = db.Column("password", db.String(30))
    resumes = db.relationship("Resume", backref="user", lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, fname, lname, username, email, pwd):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.password = pwd

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.id}', '{self.email}', '{self.username}', '{self.fname}', '{self.lname}','{self.password}')"

class Resume(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    html = db.Column('html', BLOB)
    category = db.Column("category", db.String(50))
    text = db.Column('text', db.String(300))
    headers = db.Column("headers", db.String(300))

    def __init__(self, user_id, html_in, cat, text_in, headers_in):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.html = html_in
        self.category = cat
        self.text = text_in
        self.headers = headers_in

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Resume('{self.id}', '{self.category}', '{self.text}', '{self.headers}')"
```

My problem isn't saving the data to the database however, When I run everything and try to login I get this Error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Resume' has no attribute 'username'.

and

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'models.Resume'>' has no property 'username'

I get this error when this line is run:

```
the_user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username=session.get('user')).one_or_none()
```

I don't know why this error is happening, this line is querying over the User table, not the Resume model. Does anyone know why it would throw this error?

Comment: Maybe the DB is out of sync with your data model, because you made changes after initializing the DB. Have a look inside the DB structure.

Comment: We need to see the code where the error is hapenning (not just one line) and the whole exception.